# How get EntityManager in OSGI in Abstract Class?(like spring @PersistenceContext)

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, entitymanager

I tried create BaseDao and inject EntityManager to it. In Spring I was make this:

```
public abstract class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E>{
    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "access")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public E persist(E e) {
        entityManager.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
```

but now I tried make this in OSGI and I not understand how do it. I treid write in blueprint.xml

```
<bean id="baseJpaDao" class="domain.access.impl.BaseJpaDao" >
    <jpa:context unitname="access" property="entityManager"/>
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="RequiresNew"/>
</bean>
```

and after this

```
public abstract class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E>{
    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public E persist(E e) {
        entityManager.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
```

I treid like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688492/osgi-service-jpa-persistencecontext-not-injected)

but not help.

I tried this

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("access", System.getProperties());
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

but not help.

Answer (score 1):

In Aries JPA 1.x that does not work.

In Aries JPA 2.x you can use exactly the same code as in spring. See [TaskServiceImpl.java](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/jpa/examples/tasklist-blueprint/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jpa/example/tasklist/blueprint/impl/TaskServiceImpl.java). You just need to add the [jpa:enable and jta:enable elements](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/jpa/examples/tasklist-blueprint/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/context.xml#L26-L27) to you blueprint context to activate the functionality.

Alternatively you can use the [blueprint-maven-plugin](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/pom.xml#L105-L122) to generate the whole blueprint.xml from annotations. Btw version 1.3.0 should be fine. You do not need the snapshot.

Thanks for the configuration snippets. The problem is that you use the wrong namespace for jpa. Try these:

```
xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0"
xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0"
```

Comment: my BaseJpaDao is Generic and Abstract - it normaly?

Comment: if I added <jpa:enable />
    <tx:enable-annotations />  IDE say me that this line is wrong

Comment: You also need the namespace settings from the header of the example.

Comment: Error while fetching http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0 I have Error while fetching http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 and I can not change version? where it?

Comment: when i past this link in browser http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0 I have error Not Found

Comment: Normally the namespace urls resolve to the xsds. I will try to fix the problem. It should work fine without the xsd though. The ide might show an error but it should still work at runtime.

Comment: I tried but my @PersistenceContext(unitName = "access")
    EntityManager entityManager;  IS NULL((((

Comment: If you get null then the class is not processed correctly by aries. Can you post a small example of how you do this in github or similar. I guess you have a config error somewhere.

Comment: it is my configs http://pastie.org/10747510
it is my clases http://pastie.org/10747507

Comment: I use transactions/v1.2.0 and jpa/v2.0.0 now but not help.
when I added @Transactional  my bundle not start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105364/discussion-between-christian-schneider-and-user5620472).